# Angular 8 material table with custom filter

Tags: angular, filter, angular-material, angular8, mat-table

I have used "Table retrieving data through HTTP" code from https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples for displaying data in mat-table.
I want to add custom select filter to it.
I have updated the code so that on change of the select drop down, ngAfterViewInit is called again and the select drop down value is passed to the API call, but when items per page are changed and filter is selected the API is called multiple times
Can anyone please help in implementing filter in this code

Please find below code:

TS file

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { merge, of as observableOf } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, startWith, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { PersonDetail } from '../../shared/model/people';
import { PeopleService } from '../../shared/services/people.service';

/**
 * @title People list retrieving data through HTTP
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-people-list',
  templateUrl: './people-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./people-list.component.css']
})
export class PeopleListComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  filters = [
    {value: 'aaa', viewValue: 'aaa'},
    {value: 'bbb', viewValue: 'bbb'}
  ];

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'action'];
  data: PersonDetail[] = [];

  resultsLength = 0;
  isLoadingResults = true;
  noRecords = false;
  pageSize = 10;

  filter: string = "";

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: false}) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: false}) sort: MatSort;

  constructor( private peopleService: PeopleService ) {}

  // Update page size when user has changed it
  handlePage(e: any) {
    this.pageSize = e.pageSize;
  }

  onfilterSelection( event ) {
    this.filter = event.value;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // If the user changes the sort order, reset back to the first page.
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);

    merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
    .pipe(
      startWith({}),
      switchMap(() => {
        this.isLoadingResults = true;
        return this.peopleService.getPeople( this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, this.paginator.pageIndex, this.pageSize, this.filter );
      }),
      map((data : any) => {
        // Flip flag to show that loading has finished.
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
        this.noRecords = false;
        this.resultsLength = data.total_count;

        return data.items;
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        this.isLoadingResults = false;
        // Catch if the API returned empty data.
        this.noRecords = true;
        return observableOf([]);
      })
    ).subscribe(data => this.data = data);
  }
}
```

HTML file

```
    <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <!-- Display Spinner till the results are displayed -->
  <div class="example-loading-shade" *ngIf="isLoadingResults || noRecords">
    <mat-spinner *ngIf="isLoadingResults"></mat-spinner>
    <!-- Display no records message if no data is found -->
    <div class="example-rate-limit-reached" *ngIf="noRecords">
      No records found.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="example-table-container">

    <mat-card>

      <!-- filter -->
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Apply filter</mat-label>
        <mat-select (selectionChange)="onfilterSelection($event)">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let filter of filters" [value]="filter.value">
            {{filter.viewValue}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>

    </mat-card>

    <table mat-table [dataSource]="data" class="example-table" matSort>

      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.name}}</td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Action Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Action</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- Pagination links -->
  <mat-paginator [length]="resultsLength" [pageSize]="pageSize" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20, 100]" (page)="pageEvent = handlePage($event)" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
</div>
```

I need to reload the mat-table content as per the filter selected

Comment: Can you please clear it bit more? or share your code.

Comment: @Lajwat Kumar: I have updated the question and shared the code in it

Comment: i would suggest to reload your table onchange of dropdown and remove ngAfterViewInit() event.

Comment: I think you should have to create one method to call API with filters and remove all the code from `ngAfterViewInit()` call this method when you want to refresh data like when you change dropdown value,change item per page,changing page etc.. it will fix your issue.

Comment: Solved the issue.
Replaced merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page) with this.subscription = merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page) and added this.subscription.unsubscribe(); to onfilterSelection()